Count values in exact row
I want to count number of times a specific value shoes up in an exact row. For example, the table in the picture, if I write 501 under ID and add value 3, it should count all threes in second row (id 501)...

Tried vlookup, but don't know how to count in a row found by vlookup


You may try:
=countif(filter(B2:D4,A2:A4=B7),C7)


Count value on a row based on a Range
You may also try the SUMPRODUCT
Formula:
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4=B7)*(B2:D4=C7))

and the Output is looked like this:

Reference:
SUMPRODUCT()
